# Excel VBA For Loop Error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a simple For loop which will be expanded to include more functionality later but having trouble as it keeps throwing an error "invalid next control variable reference". The code I am trying to use is listed below.

```
Sub Tickbox()

Set Location = Sheets("TickBoxSheet").Range("B:B")

i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Location)

Sheets("TickBoxSheet").Range("B2").Select


For a = 1 To i
    If Selection.Value = "True" Then
        Row = Selection.Row
        'Hide some rows in another sheet via if statements

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I don't know if I need more coffee this morning but I can't seem to figure out what the hell is going on. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While specifying the loop variable in a `Next` statement may improve performance, any gain is infinitesimal. In general, unless you have many nested loops I'd recommend against the practice, if only to avoid the problem you had here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The incremented variable (in `Next`) should be the index variable, i.e.:

```
For a = 1 To i
  '...
Next a
```

`i` is so popular as index that you should think twice before using it in other contexts.

Comment: + 1 Too fast for me. Abandoning my post LOL

Comment: *Headdesk* Yup Definitely need more coffee...

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have already got your answer from llmo. However there are few other things I would like to stress upon...

Try and avoid `.Select`. It will slow down your code.

Also It is **not necessary** that `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Location)` will give you the last row considering that you want to loop through all the rows which have data. I suggest this

```
Sub Tickbox()
    Dim i As Long, a As Long, Rw As Long

    With Sheets("TickBoxSheet")
        i = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        For a = 2 To i
            If .Range("B" & a).Value = "True" Then
                Rw = a
                'Hide some rows in another sheet via if statements
            End If
        Next a
    End With
End Sub
```

You can make it more fast using Autofilter as well so that you loop through cells which only have `True` For example

```
Sub Tickbox()
    Dim i As Long, a As Long, Rw As Long
    Dim Location As Range, acell As Range

    With Sheets("TickBoxSheet")
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        i = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        With .Range("B1:B" & i)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="True"
            Set Location = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            Debug.Print Location.Address
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        For Each acell In Location
            If acell.Value = "TRUE" Then
                Rw = acell.row
                'Hide some rows in another sheet via if statements
            End If
        Next acell
    End With
End Sub
```